# knockout get observables bound to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm making a readonly binding for knockout.

I've got it working nicely if I apply a binding to each element, as demonstrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paulinfrancis/wDJ9n/

However, I'd like to be able to set the binding to the view's root element, instead of on every form element:

```
<div data-bind="readonly: isReadonly">
    <!-- My form elements here -->
</div>

ko.bindingHandlers.readonlyView = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor){
    var isReadOnly = ko.unwrap(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
        if (isReadOnly) {
            var $elements = $(':text, :radio, :checkbox, :input', $(element));
            $elements.each(function(){
                var domElement = this;

                ko.cleanNode(domElement);

                var $domElement = $(domElement);

                if ($domElement.is(':text')) {
                    //I need the observable bound to the textbox text
                } else if ($domElement.is(':radio')) {
                    //I need to determine if the radio btn is checked
                } else if ($domElement.is(':checkbox')) {
                    //I need to determine if the checkbox is checked
                } else if($domElement.is(':input')) {
                    $domElement.prop('disabled', true);
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the viewmodel property names that the elements are bound to, so that I can  replace the existing elements with their readonly counterparts of my choice.

I can access the values I need using dataFor or contextFor, but I need to know the bound property names first:

```
ko.dataFor(domElement)['observableOne']()
ko.contextFor(domElement).$data['observableOne']()
```

I could of course parse the data-bind attribute on each element, but that seems dirty. Are there other better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Knockout "enable" or "disable" bindings would not work for you?
These could all share the same "readOnly" observable flag.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html

```
<p>
  Your cellphone number:
  <input type='text' data-bind="value: cellphoneNumber, enable: hasCellphone" />
</p>

...

var viewModel = {
    hasCellphone : ko.observable(false),
    cellphoneNumber: ""
};
```

Comment: They would absolutely work, but I'd like to remove elements like textboxes and just display the text instead. Checked checkboxes are to be displayed as checkmarks, etc. At the end of the day this all boils down do aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

I think, based on your comment to 7zark7, that what you really want are the `if` and `ifnot` bindings:

```
<label>Had caffeine fix
  <img src="checkmark.png" data-bind="if: isReadOnly() && coffeeConsumed()">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="ifnot: isReadonly, checked: coffeeConsumed">
</label>
```